# What is a letter called you send to someone who has just lost someone close to them to express your sympathy with their loss?

Tags: phrase-request

I know it's not used that often anymore, but what would Americans call a letter you send to someone who has lost someone close to express your sympathy?

I sent her a sympathy letter.

I sent her a sympathy card.

I sent her a condolence letter.

I sent her a condolence card.

Comment: Don't know about a 'letter' but the poem is called 'elegy'.

Comment: Found it... It's called 'elegiac letter'. (Look up 'elegiac'.)